# How to get needed datetime from tuple list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, tuples

i have the variable:

```
results3 = [
    (
        'CP - 2615', 
        23652, 
        datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 21, 56), 
        'custom-simulation:pre-processing-cleanup', 
        5, 
        datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 21, 59), 
        datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 22, 4), 
        259, 
        262
    ), (
        'CP - 2615', 
        23652, 
        datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 21, 56), 
        'custom-cleanup:pre-processing-cleanup', 
        1, 
        datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 22, 5), 
        datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 22, 6), 
        259, 
        262
    )
]
```

how i can get needed date time (datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 19, 22, 5)) from list of tuples, when i try:

```
actualEndTime = []
for i in range(len(results3)):
    actualEndTime.append(results3[i][2][1])
```

i got the:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1):

You went one level too deep with your indexing, the `[1]` is unneeded. Also, if all you want to do is pull the `datetime` out into a list, your code will be more readable if you use a list comprehension.

```
actualEndTime = [x[2] for x in results3]
```